# Why won't my bubble sort work? - Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, bubble-sort

I'm trying to alphabetically sort an arraylist of objects by the object's variable which is named "name". Here is the code I wrote to do so:

```
public void sortName()
    {
        int j;

        for ( j = 0;  j < theBatters.size()-1;  j++)
        {
            System.out.println(theBatters.get(j).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(theBatters.get(j+1).getName()));
            if ( theBatters.get(j).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(theBatters.get(j).getName()) > 0 )
            {                                             // ascending sort
                Collections.swap(theBatters, j, j+1);
                j=0;
            } 
        } 
    }
```

I believe the problem has something to do with the line where swap is used, for when I print the arraylist after I use this sortName() method everything is in the same order, despite this line returning values greater than 0 when it is supposed to:

```
System.out.println(theBatters.get(j).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(theBatters.get(j+1).getName()));
```

Comment: In your if statement, why are you comparing get(j) to get(j) again?

Comment: @AndrewtheProgrammer found the bug. You want to have `theBatter.get(j+1)` in your `if` statement in the `compareToIgnoreCase` method.

Comment: Glad I could help, I know that simple mistakes like that are a pain to find just by looking at it

Comment: *facepalm* such an idiot haha thanks guys

Comment: Lack of change is caused by fact that you are comparing name of same object. While you are printing result of comparing, you are using `get(j)` and `get(j+1)`, but in your `if` you are having `get(j)` twice. Other problem which you may face is that you are setting `j` to `0` at end of iteration. But after each iteration `j++` will be executed, so at start of next one, your `j` will become `1`. Take it into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The very name of bubble sort means that there is bubble of sorted and unsorted items. You simply forgot about this fact. Here is working (I hope) code:

```
    public void sortName()
        {

            for ( int i = 0;  i < theBatters.size()-1;  i++) // bigger outer bubble
            for ( int j = i+1;  j < theBatters.size()-1;  j++) // smaller inner bubble
            {                   System.out.println(theBatters.get(i).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(theBatters.get(j).getName()));
                if ( theBatters.get(i).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(theBatters.get(j).getName()) > 0 )
                {                                             // ascending sort
                    Collections.swap(theBatters, i, j);
                    // j=0; // Not necessary and confusing. It is already in good order
                } 
            } 
        }
```